# connect-redis setup in typescript

Tags: typescript

Based on docs, this is how to create a redisstore:

```
var session = require('express-session');
var RedisStore = require('connect-redis')(session);

app.use(session({
    store: new RedisStore(options),...
}));
```

I am converting them to typescript:

```
import * as session from 'express-session';
import * as RedisStore from 'connect-redis';

app.use(session({
    store: new (RedisStore(session))(options),...
}));
```

However, I am getting an error.  How do you convert this line of code:
`var RedisStore = require('connect-redis')(session);`

Answer (score 11):

I have figured it out:

```
import * as session from 'express-session';
import * as connectRedis from 'connect-redis';
let RedisStore = connectRedis(session);

app.use(session({
    store: new RedisStore({client: redis.createClient(6379, "localhost")}),...
}));
```

Answer (score 6):

This works:

```
import connectRedis from 'connect-redis';
import session from 'express-session';
const RedisStore = connectRedis(session);

 app.use(
        session({
            secret: 'secret',
            store: new RedisStore({host: '127.0.0.1', port: 6379}),
            resave: false,
            saveUninitialized: false
        })
    );
```

Answer (score 1):

**Basic Redis Setup**

import statements

```js
const express = require('express');

const session = required('express-session');

const redis = require('redis');

const connectRedis = require('connect-redis');

const app = express();

app.use(express.json())
```

connect to redis store

```js
const RedisStore = connectRedis(session);

//config redis 

const redisClient = redis.createClient({

port: 6379,

host: 'localhost'

});
```

configure session middleware

```js
app.use(session({

store: new RedisStore({client: redisClient}),

secret: 'mySecret',

saveUninitialized: false,

resave: false,

name:'sessionId',

cookie: {

//secure false for non https request , keep false in production

secure: false,

// if true, prevents client side JS from reading the cookie

httpOnly: true,

//session age in millisec // 30 mins

maxAge: 1000 * 60 * 30

}

}));
```